# Automate API key generation on Google Cloud

Tags: firebase, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-api-gateway

We're currently working on our API based on Google Cloud Functions together with Google's API Gateway.

As every customer who buys access to our API should get their own API key, I'm wondering if there's a ways to create those API keys using and API. What I want to achieve is that a customer is able to request an API key in their own settings, so klick a button, this triggers a function, generates a key and shows it to the customer in front end.

After searching for quite some time, I didn't find anything about how this could be built. It could also be that my approach to this is totally wrong - if that's the case, please roast me and give me some advice with it!

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google credentials can not be created programmttlcy they must be created manually.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Too bad though.

Comment: I have been saying that for around eight years now.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there is something. A while in beta (more than 1 years ago) and quickly back in alpha, and undocumented (or pretty bad)

As you can see in the gcloud alpha command, you can use API Keys with CLI and API. Use this command to test and discover more how you can use API keys.

```
gcloud alpha services api-keys create --display-name="created by API" --log-http
```

---

**USE WITH CAUTION**

Firstly, I have no update on this API, will it survive or not? The lifecycle and the "no news" from Google is strange and keep in mind that the API can be removed at any time.

Secondly, API Keys is a long lived token and it's not recommended for security reason. But sometime, it's better than nothing, so to use it when no others solution are possible, it's acceptable. Else, prefer OAuth .

Eventually, API Keys authenticate a project, not a customer/user. You won't have it in header data after the API Gateway request forward. Only the Project ID (or Number, I don't remember). Thus, if you want to differentiate each customer/user, you need to create different projects, and generate a keys in each project. Same thing if you implement rate limit on API Gateway: Quotas are per project and not per API Keys.